# How to put each 3 elements of an array into another array, and keep repeating

Tags: php

I have an $array = array() which has many elements. I want to have a $parent_array whereby each element of $parent_array is an array which contains 3 elements from $array, consecutively.

So for a concrete example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
$array = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$parent_array = (array('a','b','c'),array('d','e','f'), array('g','h','i'), array('j'));
```

Please note I need this to work if the $array only has 1, 2 or 3 elements in it. Most of the time it has hundreds.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you're looking for [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is what you're looking for:

```
$parent_array = array_chunk($array, 3);
```

Which, given your example, would output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      3 => string 'd' (length=1)
      4 => string 'e' (length=1)
      5 => string 'f' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array
      6 => string 'g' (length=1)
      7 => string 'h' (length=1)
      8 => string 'i' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array
      9 => string 'j' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

array chunk is your friend ;)

```
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$result = array_chunk($array, 3);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$myArray = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$parent = array_chunk($myArray,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$parent_array = array();
foreach($array as $val)
{
   if ($i++ % 3 == 0)
   {
      $parent_array[++$j] = array();
   $parent_array[$j][] = $val;
}
```

$parent_array will be a bi-dimensional array.